# Matplotlib `fill_between`: Remove thin boundary

Tags: matplotlib, sage

Consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

graph_data = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [5, 8, 7, 9]]
x = range(len(graph_data[0]))
y = graph_data[1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

alpha = 0.5
plt.plot(x, y, '-o',markersize=3,  color=[1., alpha, alpha], markeredgewidth=0.0)
ax.fill_between(x, 0, y, facecolor=[1., alpha, alpha], interpolate=False)    

plt.show()
filename = 'test1.pdf'
fig.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight')
```

It works fine. However, when zoomed in the generated PDF, I can see two thin gray/black boundaries that separate the line:

[image]

I can see this when viewing in both Edge and Chrome. My question is, how can I get rid of the boundaries?

**UPDATE** I forgot to mention, I was using [Sage](http://sagemath.org) to generate the graph. Now it seems a problem specific to Sage (and not to Python in general). This time I used native Python, and got correct result.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this in any of the pdf viewers I use. Maybe worth noting that Edge and Chrome are not generally good pdf viewers.

Comment: Do not use `from pylab import *`, it overwrites python builtins and is considered bad practice. Import `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `numpy as np` and use those shorthands.

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce it but maybe you can try to not plot the line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

graph_data = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [5, 8, 7, 9]]
x = range(len(graph_data[0]))
y = graph_data[1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

alpha = 0.5
plt.plot(x, y, 'o',markersize=3,  color=[1., alpha, alpha])
ax.fill_between(x, 0, y, facecolor=[1., alpha, alpha], interpolate=False)    

plt.show()
filename = 'test1.pdf'
fig.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight')
```